# Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous then $g(x) = 1/f(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I was asked to prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous then $g(x) = 1/f(x)$ is continuous at every point x where $f(x) \ne 0$.

I have gotten to this point

$|g(x) - g(y)| = |1/f(x) - 1/f(y)| = |(f(y) - f(x)) / f(x)f(y)|$

Not quite sure what step to take next.

Comment: Do you know that a composition of continuous functions is continous?

Comment: I believe so though I don't know how I would use that here.

Comment: x @Megan: Consider $h\circ f$ where $h(y)=1/y$.

Answer (score 4):

The composition of two continuous functions is continuous. To compute $g(x) = 1/f(x)$, you take $f(x)$ and compute its reciprocal. Let $h(x) = 1/x$ be the reciprocal function. Then $g(x) = h(f(x))$. Because $h$ and $f$ are continuous, their composition is continuous (everywhere where $f(x)\neq 0$).

This is a shortcut method; rather than proving the fact directly using the definition of continuity, you're using a fact that has been proved about how continuous functions fit together.

Comment: And the continuity of the reciprocal function is particularly easy to show, using the fact that a surjective monotone function from one open interval to another is continuous.

Comment: But that "fact" is not "particularly easy to show", compared to a direct proof of continuity of the reciprocal function.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere,

$$\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h)=f(x)$$

Then,

$$\frac{1}{\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h)}=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{f(x+h)}=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$

Which gives

$$\lim_{h \to 0}g(x+h)=g(x)$$

So $g(x)$ is also continuous everywhere

Comment: I believe the proof is supposed to show that if $f$ is continuous, so is $g$, but maybe similar argument applies.

Comment: @user326210 Thanks for the reminder

Comment: That's proof by assertion - why is it true that the second equation implies the third? That is the heart of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0)\ne 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\eta>0$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in[x_0-\eta,x_0+\eta]$. Let $$M = \min\{|f(x)|: x_0-\eta\leq x\leq x_0+\eta\}$$ (this minimum exists since closed intervals are compact). Let $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $\delta\in(0,\eta)$ such that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<M|f(x_0)|\varepsilon$$ for $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. It follows then that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$,

\begin{align}
\left| \frac1{f(x)}-\frac1{f(x_0)}\right| &= \left| \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{f(x)f(x_0)} \right|\\
& =\frac1{|f(x)|}\frac1{|f(x_0)|}|f(x)-f(x_0)|\\
&< \frac1{|f(x)|}\frac1{|f(x_0)|} M|f(x_0)|\varepsilon\\
&\leqslant\varepsilon,
\end{align}
from which we conclude.

Comment: Doesn't this proof require the additional assumption that $f$ is defined on $[x_0-\eta,x_0+\eta]$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)\neq 0$ we have $|f(x)|>\gamma$ for some $\gamma>0$, and there exists $\delta_1$ such that for arbitrary $y\in [x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1]$ we have $|f(y)|>\gamma$

That is to say $$|g(x)-g(y)|<\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\gamma^2}$$

And since f is continuous, for arbitrary M we have $\delta_2$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{M}{\gamma^2}$ for any $y\in[x-\delta_2,x+\delta_2]$, that is to say
$$|g(x)-g(y)|<M$$
for arbitrary y such that $|y-x|<\delta$, $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$
which is exactly the definition of continuity.